# Xforms plugin on wordpress over night became totally unusable.

Tags: wordpress, xforms

we used Xforms for our visitors to fill in, and over a night the plugin got totally unusable.

I'm wondering if anyone know why this happened and how to fix it?
We've already tried to uninstall & install X forms but it doesn't help.

I can't post pictures of how it looks since I need 10 in reputation and I just registered here but maybe someone still can help me?

Comment: What do you mean by `got totally unusable`?

Comment: No links availably, can't wright anything, can´t change my forms

Comment: Here's a link. not sure this okay
But this is how it looks:

Comment: https: //www.dropbox.com/s/a2y98xuwj0sglkf/Screenshot%202014-04-09%20kl.%2015.29.11.png
Without the space between https: and //

Comment: and this https: //www.dropbox.com/s/wos0y4dprghay3h/Screenshot%202014-04-09%20kl.%2015.29.23.png

it all looks like this.. I can't edit anything. There's no buttons.. just text.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following steps to troubleshoot:

- Is the form read only: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Read_Only
- Is the browser still supported: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Installing_and_Testing
- Is the Wordpress plugin still supported: http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=xform